# rdlc Globalisation

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I have a globalstrings.resx resource file in my solution which contains all of my key/value pairs for all static labels and tooltips. Everything in my web application has been globalized excepting for my .rdlc files. I've had a look at this solution - [RDLC_Localization](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/RDLC_Localization.aspx) - but it does not solve the **problem of globalizing the paging, filtering and exporting text and tooltips**.

How would solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that paging, filtering and exporting static labels and tooltips are not part of the .rdlc file but are a part of the ReportViewer control in ASP.NET.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251661.aspx for the solution.